# Google Calendar api ignores timezone

Tags: flutter, google-calendar-api

Im using the CalendarApi in flutter and in order to get events I use the list method like that:

```
calendarApi.events.list(
  cls.calendarId,
  timeZone: <specific timezone>
  timeMin: DateTime.now().today().toUtc(),
  timeMax: DateTime.now().tomorrow().toUtc(),
),
```

No matter what timezone I tried it always return the event start and end date in UTC format.
I tried using the timezones in multiple formats:

1. America/Los_Angeles
2. UTC - 08:00
3. GMT format
4. Pacific Standard Time

None of the following worked.
In addition in the in google calendar's settings the timezone is set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

> Must be an RFC3339 timestamp with mandatory time zone offset, for example, 2011-06-03T10:00:00-07:00, 2011-06-03T10:00:00Z. Milliseconds may be provided but are ignored. If timeMax is set, `timeMin` must be smaller than `timeMax`.

Make sure the strings you are sending follow one of these pattens:

```
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS±HH:MM
```

or

```
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ
```

So for example, the time that this answer was posted would be:

```
2021-07-27T16:08:02+02:00
```

or:

```
2021-07-27T14:08:02Z
```

Where the `Z` signifies 'Zulu', or UTC.

Comment: I cant decide the String format of the date since the timeMin and timeMax arguments take DateTime object and not a String.

Comment: Then use [`.toISOString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString)A to send the timestamp.

Comment: But the argument does not take a string it takes a DateTime object

Comment: I would suggest trying it before rebutting the answer :)